# Не верно работает background-size:cover

Tags: html, css

[image: Скриншот]

`background-size: cover;` - не масштабирует изображение под размер экрана по ширине, оно выезжает за края, попробовал уже все что можно было, но мне кажется что я что-то упустил и проблема элементарная.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(/images/Layer_15.jpg) center no-repeat, url(/images/picture.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>MoGo</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Используйте ```background-size: contain;``` чтобы сохранять пропорции, либо ```background-size: 100% 100%;``` чтобы все вмещалось и по высоте и по ширине (но без пропорций).

Comment: cover не масштабирует элемент под размер экрана, как вы хотите

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в CSS строчку:

```
body { margin: 0; padding:0; }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding:0; }
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(/images/Layer_15.jpg) center no-repeat, url(/images/picture.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>MoGo</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите растягивать картинку вусмерть, чтобы картинка маштабировалась под размер экрана - пишите `background-size: 100% 100%`.
**Но:**  background на этом интро не является тем, что пользователь обязательно должен увидеть, это просто элемент декорации, людям не важно видеть орла полностью.

Вот пример с растянутым вусмерть орлом: (Не надо так делать)

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i13y.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>MoGo</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

А вот `background-size: cover`, это лучше подходит для этого:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i13y.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>MoGo</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```